# Do I need to drop or deallocate a temporary table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've written a few scripts that declare a TABLE and a CURSOR.  At the end of the script, I deallocate the CURSOR.  Am I also supposed to deallocate the TABLE?

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (columns);
INSERT @MyTable(columns) VALUES (values)
INSERT @MyTable(columns) VALUES (values)
...

DECLARE workorders SCROLL CURSOR FOR
SELECT (rest of statement);

... work...

CLOSE workorders;
DEALLOCATE workorders;
```

Comment: You dont need to explicitly close and deallocate the cursor either if you declare it in a different way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737586/tsql-cursor-how-to-check-if-already-declared-and-thus-deallocate/8743428#8743428

Answer (score 3):

The *scope* of a `table variable` is with in the specific batch. So you don't have to explicitly do anything to `drop/deallocate` the space occupied by table variable.

The space occupied by the `table variable` will be automatically dropped in the end of batch where it got created

Answer (score 1):

First, can you avoid the cursor?  If so, rewrite the code in a set based manner (operate on many rows all at once, not one at a time).

Second, if you can't, can you use a LOCAL FAST_FORWARD cursor?

Third, you are correct - you definitely need to deallocate the cursor.

Fourth, you're putting multiple rows into a @table variable, which [doesn't have statistics](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dave_ballantynes_blog/2011/12/02/mythbusting_13201C20_table-variables-have-no-statistics_1D20_/).

- Don't do that - use a #temp table instead, and see if putting indexes on it are a net gain, or a net loss, by using Profiler for SQL:BatchCompleted, and looking at Reads, Writes, CPU, and Duration!

  - Unless you're passing the @table variable as an argument, which in your post, you aren't

Fifth, in general, it's a good practice to drop your #temp tables when they're done.  You don't need to bother for @table variables.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.  This is a simple "automation" script meant to bypass the manual data entry on certain tables.  I can't use FAST_FORWARD cursor as I have to loop through that cursor a couple of times.  The @table will probably only contain at most 3 records, the cursor probably at most 50 - usually more like 10 or 20.  Using statistics doesn't make sense on such a small table and query.

Comment: @TLamb - are you sure using statistics doesn't make sense?  Check out what Profiler says for RPC:Completed or SQL:BatchCompleted, in the Reads, Writes, CPU, and Duration columns.  In general, I have found that the times that an table variable provides a meaningful, or even measurable, advantage over a #temp table to be very, very few - and as your systems grow over time, even fewer, so unless you actually know of - or measured - a solid reason to use a table variable, I would always recommend the #temp table as a starting point.

Comment: I don't remeber where I learned this, but all I really need is a couple multi-dimensional arrays to loop through.  From what I read, the only way to do that in SQL is with a temporary table or table variable... sorry I don't have the reference.  The table inserts are so small that I thought creating then destroying temporary tables would be a lot more taxing on the server.  I will investigate a little further... inquiring minds want to know!  I thank you so much for taking time to respond and educate!

Comment: @TLamb - Don't go looping through things in SQL - it's absolutely terrible for performance.  Instead, figure out what needs to happen to each set of rows, and do it to every matching row at once.  Note that you can use CASE statements in both INSERT and UPDATE statements so you can hit more than one condition in a single statement, if need be.